# WPF Dispatcher Invoke return value is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I have a call to a method that returns a `UIElement` that I call using the `Dispatcher`, below is the code.

However the return value of the `Dispatcher` invoke is always NULL, any ideas?

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var slides = (IList<UIElement>)e.Argument;
    var bmpSlides = new List<UIElement>();
    var imageService = new ImageService();
    int count = 0;

    foreach (UIElement slide in slides)
    {
        object retVal = slide.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new ThreadStart(() => imageService.GenerateProxyImage(slide)));
        bmpSlides.Add(imageService.GenerateProxyImage(slide));
        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(count / 100 * slides.Count);
        count++;
    }

    e.Result = bmpSlides;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'oh, here's how to do what you are trying to do:

```
object retVal;
slide.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => retval = imageService.GenerateProxyImage(slide)));
```

**Edit:** The ThreadStart threw me off - this isn't multithreaded. What are you trying to accomplish with this code sample??

Comment: This will work, but it seems cleaner to me to use Func<T> as described in other answers.

Comment: Well actually Dispatcher.Invoke waits for the thread to complete, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke doesn't...

Answer (score 7):

It's because `ThreadStart` doesn't have a return type (`void()`).

Try this instead:

```
UIElement retVal = slide.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<UIElement>( () => imageService.GenerateProxyImage(slide)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509.aspx) for `Dispatcher.Invoke` states the return value is "The return value from the delegate being invoked or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the delegate has no return value." Since the `ThreadStart` delegate you are using is void, you need to use a `Func<T>` or a custom delegate with a return value.