# C# WPF multithreading cannot return the actual value from Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in VS2013

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, action

I would like to get the return value from a thread in C# VS2013 WPF.

The code is:

```
int t = 0;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    t = myFucntion(myObject) // if I do not use dispatcher, myObject cannot be accessed by the calling thread. 
));
return t;
```

Why t is always 0 and not return the actual value ? 
The solution here does not work for me.

[WPF Dispatcher Invoke return value is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394028/wpf-dispatcher-invoke-return-value-is-always-null)

**UPDATE**

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
        {
          t = myFunction(myObject));
        }));
return t;
```

**But, t is not assigned to the actual value returned from myFunction.**

Comment: my guess is that method does not wait for your thread. so it will return 0 before your thread be able to store results in `t`

Comment: Not sure what is your intention here is to use Dispatcher object as you are updating any UI item. You can move the logic to calculate `t' either in `BackgroudWorker` or `Task` and in completed event, update the UI element in Dispatch.BeginInvoke if there are any.

Comment: @user1672994,  if I do not use dispatcher, myObject cannot be accessed by the calling thread.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE in OP.

Answer (score 0):

[`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647500(v=vs.110).aspx) is asynchronous. It will return immediatly after queuing the delegate to the message loop:

> Executes the specified delegate **asynchronously** at the specified
>   priority on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.

That means that you have a race-condition, and you might even see `t` actually contain the *expected* value if you run it enough times.

To eliminate that, If you want to wait until the delegate is ran on the message loop, use `Dispatcher.Invoke` instead:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                                      new Action(() => t = myFunction()));
```

Comment: based on your code, I got error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll. Additional information: Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE in OP.

Comment: the value of t is not assigned to the actual value returned from myFunction.

Comment: @user3750163 Then what value does it return?

Comment: "t" can only get its default value 0.

Comment: What are you doing inside `myFunction`?

Comment: myFunction() do some calculations and return an integer value that should be assigned to t.

Comment: @user3750163 I don't have any idea what you're doing wrong. When running this code locally, it works fine.